# Infinity in QSqlQueryModel

Tags: qt, postgresql

I use `QSqlQueryModel` to query a postgresql database， I found that all the `Infinity` and `-Infinity` values (double precision) in the database I get using `model->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole)` is `QVariant(double, 0)`.  My Qt version is 4.8.3. How could I correctly get the inf/-inf value in my C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check special values in your select query like this:

```
QSqlQuery q("select case field1 when 'Infinity' then '+INF' when '-Infinity' then '-INF' else cast(field1 as varchar(12)) end from table1");
model->setQuery(q);
model->select();
```

Note that I had to cast double precision to varchar as well.